# Combine two different models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two **unrelated** models:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fieldB = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    fieldC = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fieldD = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to build **one** serilaizer with DRF so that I can have a returned **json** like this one:

```
},...
{ 'fieldA' : 'a',
  'fieldB' : 'b',
  'fieldC' : 'c',
  'fieldD' : 'd'
}, ...
```

I'm unable to do it right now. I've tried [this module](https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels) but I run into an [error](https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels/issues/12).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class ModelOneSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``ModelOne``.
    """
    class Meta(object):
        model = ModelOne


class ModelTwoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``ModelTwo``.
    """
    user = ModelOneSerializer()

    class Meta(object):
        model = ModelTwo
```

Comment: Ok. And how is it going to be used in the viewset :  `ModelTwoSerializer(ModelTwo.objects.all())` ?

Comment: maybe with qs1.union(qs2)? may work? I'm not sure if filters will work...

Comment: This is not an answer. This answer just noticed the standard ModelSerializer.

Answer (score -1):

As marin said, you can do this:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class ModelOneSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``ModelOne``.
    """
    class Meta(object):
        model = ModelOne


class ModelTwoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``ModelTwo``.
    """ 
    class Meta(object):
        model = ModelTwo

class ModelThreeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``ModelThree``.
    """
    class Meta(object):
        model = ModelThree

class ModelFourSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``ModelFour``.
    """    
    modelone = ModelOneSerializer()
    modeltwo = ModelTwoSerializer()
    modelthree = ModelThreeSerializer()
    # make it like modelthree = ModelThreeSerializer(source="get_field_from_other_model) if you have foreign key between the models.


    class Meta(object):
        model = ModelFour
        fields = ("modelone", "modeltwo"..)
```

And you also can

```
class CombineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    modelone = ModelOneSerializer()
    modeltwo = ModelTwoSerializer()
    modelthree = ModelThreeSerializer()
    ....
```

#### EDIT

Try: overwrite get_queryset method and use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
class YourList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = YourModel.objects.select_related() #use select_related to join table and handle the query.
```

Comment: See comment on **marin** post. Beside, this doesn't produce an output where the different fields are at the same level in the json file like I said in http://stackoverflow.com/q/39143451/2219080 . I want something like https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic-usage.html but the example doesn't work.

Comment: What you want to do with this code ?ModelTwoSerializer(ModelTwo.objects.all())

Comment: How do you provide the queryset to the serializer ?

Comment: @iMitwe, Please correct me if I misunderstand what you want.

Comment: The resulting Json won't be aligned the way I want it. I end up implementing the https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels way.

Answer (score -1):

I can see that this question is still receiving answers, years after I actually solved the problem. As I said in the comments, I ended up implementing the [DjangoRestMultipleModels](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples) way.